# Calling BaseGameActivity methods from inside a SurfaceView

Tags: google-play-services

I've imported com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity to use the Google Play Services.  I've got the TypeANumber sample app up and running perfectly.  I'm trying to reverse code the Google Play Services back into my own app.

How can I use BaseGameActivity.beginUserInitiatedSignIn() from inside a SurfaceView?  I can not extend the BaseGameActivity because I have all ready extended the SurfaceView class.  I've searched and have not found any help that I can use.  The best I can get is that Eclipse is telling me that beginUserInitiatedSignIn() is not visible.  How can I make it visible to use?

Comment: can it be a static method?..

Comment: The beginUserInitiatedSignIn() method is not static.

Comment: is it and can it be are two different things, I was asking if you can make the method static which would probably be the quickest fix otherwise you need to provide a bit of code so we can see how the SurfaceView is setup and its relationship to the Activity.

Comment: It's the imported BaseGameActivity (and all its methods) for the Google Play Services, not one of my methods.  I just want to know if there's a way to call the methods of BaseGameActivity from inside a SurfaceView.  Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: ok, how do yo usetup your surfaceview.  Did you create a view class and extend Surfaceview or did you assign the layout?   What you will want to do is Create a class view that extends surfaceview and pass in a reference to the BaseGameActivity.  This will allow you to call the methods on the instance of BaseGameActivity as long  as its public.  If not you may need to create a class that extends the BaseGameActvity so you can interact with the methods of that instance.

Comment: I created a view class that extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback.  How would I pass in a reference?  Thanks for helping @Sorceri, I've been working on this so long, I'm getting confused with the simple things.

Comment: Show your code and I can help better, just need the code in the extended BaseGameActivity class that creates the Surfaceview, and the constructors in the surfaceview class.   We will basically change the constructor in the surfaceview class to take a reference to a BaseGameActivity.  If you dont have a class that extends the BaseGameActivity then we will want to create one so we have more control.

Comment: You gave me the answer I needed in your last comment!  Thanks!